How to Trigger an API Call Before Leaving a Page When User Clicks the Back Button in React JS?
I'm working on a React application where I need to trigger an API call (specifically, the SaveMeasurements() function) before the user navigates away from the current page by clicking the back button on the browser. I also want to redirect the user to a specific route /studylist after the API call is triggered.
This code works as expected when the user clicks the back button without refreshing the page. However, if the user refreshes the page and then clicks the back button, the browser's history stack seems to reset, and the user is navigated to the previous tab in Chrome instead of being redirected to /studylist.
const handlePopState = (event: PopStateEvent) => {
  // Prevent navigation if it's due to a popstate event
  if (event.state && event.state.preventBack) {
    console.log("Back button was pressed.");

    SaveMeasurements();
    // Redirect to a specific route instead of going back
    navigate("/studylist", { replace: true });
  }
};

/**
 * @description
 * Intercepts back button navigation, triggers SaveMeasurements for auto-saving, and redirects to /studylist.
 */
useEffect(() => {
  // Add a state to the history stack to control back navigation
  window.history.replaceState({ preventBack: true }, "");

  window.addEventListener("popstate", handlePopState);

  // Push a new state to history to handle the initial load
  window.history.pushState({ preventBack: true }, "", window.location.href);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("popstate", handlePopState);
  };
}, [navigate]);

How can I ensure that the SaveMeasurements() function is always called and that the user is correctly redirected to /studylist even after a page refresh?

Try using beforeunload event. Here is the updated code.
const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
    SaveMeasurements();
    navigate("/studylist", { replace: true });
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    };
}, []); // Update your dependecies based on requirements

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        SaveMeasurements();
    };
}, []); // Update your dependecies based on requirements

The first useEffect will handle browser refresh and call the API. The second useEffect will handle normal back navigation.
